# Eclipse programmatic relaunch with new vmargs, vmargs not present on restart

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to do a programmatic restart of my eclipse based application, as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539601/adding-extra-system-properties-to-an-eclipse-programmatic-restart) .This would require me to set the eclipse.exitcode as 24 also eclipse.exitdata. Also set the new command line args and the vmargs.

So I have added my own implementation of switch workspace (followed from the OpenWorkspaceAction implementation to set the command line args and the vmargs).

I am able to see the vmargs getting set before eclipse restarts.
But after eclipse restarts, I am trying to read the vmargs but they appear to be unset.

Comment: How are you reading the vmargs?

Comment: String arg = System.getProperty("my.vmarg");

Comment: What is "my.vmarg"? Why do you think that should be set as a system property?

Comment: So I actually want this other control flow to be enabled after the restart. So the vm arg which I am setting is 
`-Dswitch.tenant=true`. 

Upon restart I will read it as a System property 
`Boolean arg = Boolean.getBoolean("switch.tenant");`